# Substitue $_REQUEST

Tags: javascript, php, request, global

I know enough code to be dangerous, but couldn't write something from scratch if my life depended on it.  I'm migrating a website to new hosting that has a newer version of PHP which doesn't allow $_REQUEST (I think).  This code is designed to encrypt a PDF.  Works great on the old site (probably older version of PHP).
I tried replacing all the $_REQUEST with $_GET and that didn't work.  Any help is greatly appreciated. I excluded the formatting code and basic html.

```
<?php
$timeArr = explode( ' ', microtime( ) );
$pageStartTime = $timeArr[ 1 ] + $timeArr[ 0 ];

$file = $_FILES['file'];
if($_REQUEST['submit'] && (!trim($_REQUEST['password']) || $_REQUEST['password'] == 'Password')) {
    $msg = 'Please enter a password.';
}
elseif(is_array($file) && $file['error'] == 0) {
    $enc_path = 'encrypted';
    $src = $file['tmp_name'];
    $dest = "{$enc_path}/{$file['name']}";
    $pass = trim($_REQUEST['password']);
    $cmd_fmt = "pdftk '$src' output '$dest' user_pw '$pass'";

    @mkdir($enc_path);
    @system($cmd_fmt);

    if(file_exists($dest)) $file_url = "http://www.company.com/{$enc_path}/" . rawurlencode($file['name']); 

}
?>

        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function copyToClipboard(s) {
            if(window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData) {
                clipboardData.setData('text', s);
            }
            else alert('Could not get permission to access the clipboard. Please copy the URL from the text box instead.');
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
    <div style="width: 600px;">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <center>
        <form action="<?= $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="/logo.png" border="0" style="height: 145px; margin-bottom: -10px;">
            <h1>PDF Encryption Tool</h1>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <? if($file_url) : ?>
            <span><a href="<?= $file_url ?>">Click here to download your file</a></span><br/>
            <input type="text" readonly value="<?= $file_url ?>" style="width: 350px; margin: 0 0 5px 0;"><br/>
            <input type="button" onclick="copyToClipboard('<?= $file_url ?>');" value="Copy to Clipboard">
            <br/>
        <? elseif($_REQUEST['submit'] && $msg) : ?> 
            <font color="red"><b><?= $msg ?></b></font>
            <br/>
        <? elseif($_REQUEST['submit']) : ?> 
            <font color="red"><b>There was an error processing your request. This program only accepts PDF files.</b></font>
            <br/>
        <? endif; ?>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="file" name="file" style="width: 350px; border: 0; margin: 0 0 5px 0;"><br/>
        <input id="password" type="text" name="password" style="width: 350px;"
            <?= $_REQUEST['password'] ? 'class="focus"' : ''?>
            onFocus="this.className = 'focus'; if( this.value == 'Password' ) { this.value = ''; }"
            onBlur="if( this.value == '' ) { this.className = ''; this.value = 'Password'; }"
            onKeyDown="if( event.keyCode == 13 ) { this.form.submit( ); return false; }"
            value="<?= $_REQUEST['password'] ? $_REQUEST['password'] : 'Password' ?>"
        >
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
        </form>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </center>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <?
    $timeArr = explode( ' ', microtime( ) );
    $pageEndTime = $timeArr[ 1 ] + $timeArr[ 0 ];
    $pageTime = $pageEndTime - $pageStartTime;
    ?>
    <span align="left">
        <font color="gray" size="-3">
            Page took <?= number_format( $pageTime, 3 ) ?> second(s) to load.
        </font>
    </span>
    </div>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the $_REQUEST var can contains $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE values! see [http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php](reserved.variables.request)

Comment: your form for example is of type $_POST

Comment: you also have some serious security issues in the page, you can basicly run any command with `@system($cmd_fmt);`

Comment: `method="POST"` so use `$_POST` not `$_GET`.

Comment: So I need to ....
1. replace $_REQUEST with $_POST
2. replace @system($cmd_fmt) with.....?

Comment: Why don't you test the $_REQUEST super global first?

Answer (score 0):

> $_REQUEST: An associative array that by default contains the contents
>   of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE. [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Your form uses method "post":

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

this means you need to replace your `$_REQUEST` with `$_POST`

For the security issues: always think what the user can manipulate be and how it could be used to break your code.

For your commandline you could use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/de/function.escapeshellarg.php). You also have serveral User-Variables which can be used in Html. See [cross-site scripting](http://excess-xss.com/)